# Converting Http JSON Response to Object with HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to convert the Http post response to the Type object

JSON Response from the server

```
{
    "authenticated": false,
    "admin": false
}
```

Angular class to be type casted

```
export class UserRole {
  authenticated: boolean;
  admin: boolean;
}
```

HTTP Post Call

```
login() {
    this.user.password = btoa(this.user.password);
    this.http.post(this.url, this.user).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
    });
    if (this.userRole.admin) {
        console.log('Going in admin');
       this.authService.setLoggedIn(this.user.userId,true);
    } else {
      console.log('Going in else admin');
      this.authService.setLoggedIn(this.user.userId,false);
    }
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/nav');
  }
```

I am having issues on converting the result on subscribe to UserRole object, should i need to use a JSON.parse or any other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a type argument to have the type flowed through to the subscriber:

```
this.http.post<UserRole>(this.url, this.user).subscribe(res => {
   console.log(res);
});
```

This should set the type of your `res` parameter, so you can use `res.authenticated` et al.

Comment: Ok got it. Is there any way of getting the object value itself gets assigned to this.userRole as the instance is on the main component   this.userRole=res?